# What's the difference between "the lack" and "the lacking"?

Tags: vocabulary

In the following sentence, my teacher says that *the lacking* should be *the lack*, instead.

> The lacking of trees may lead to global warming.

If it's wrong, would someone mind explaining why it is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"Lacking" and "lack" are two different words and they have different meanings:

> [lack](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lack) — (noun) deficiency or absence of something needed, desirable, or customary: lack of money; lack of skill.
>
> [lacking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lacking) — (adjective) wanting; deficient: He was found lacking in stamina.

When you say "the lacking of trees" you are meaning "the trees' lacking" which means that the *trees themselves* are lacking something. Your teacher is correct. You should use "lack" in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any rule that mandates one noun form versus another; lacking and lack are both nouns. However, I've never read the word "lacking" used where "lack" also works. Perhaps what makes it sound awkward is that "lacking" is usually used as a verb. Ex: Lacking a lake, the dry county was not a popular spot for fishing, or for drinking. Using "the lacking" in your sentence jars with the expectation of "the lack"; it is not wrong, but just clumsy-sounding and overly wordy.

Answer (score -4):

Well technically you can tell her that the lacking of grammatical knowledge may lead to poor English teaching. She is probably going by the "does this sound right?" rule instead of actually looking at the rules. Tell her you are using Lacking as a noun and she can't even argue back while maintaining credibility.

While the lacking of trees has been linked to global warming, It's hard to tell how many trees are enough.

Comment: Are you suggesting that a sentence such as: *"The lacking of books in a library may lead to its closure"* is grammatically correct/acceptable?

Comment: I'm unaware of any rules dictating the avoidance of a conjunction immediately preceding a gerund phrase. It's awkward and uninspired, but it aint wrong. If you can tell me why: 'The lacking of books' is not a gerund phrase I will break my eternal vow not to engage in self-censorship by deleting my comments. Everything is on record at the NSA anyways.

Comment: Please, see this [link on Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+lacking+of+books%2Cthe+lack+of+books%2Cthe+lacking+of+trees%2Cthe+lack+of+trees&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20lack%20of%20books%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20lack%20of%20trees%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I think I see the point you are trying to make: that OP and I should popularize the use of 'The lacking.' Just because people don't use it, doesn't make it a grammar breach.

Comment: “Does it sound right” is vastly superior to prescriptive rules as a gauge of whether you should use a form or construction; cf. “Colourless green ideas sleep furiously”. “The lacking of trees” is unidiomatic and sounds strange. That simple. I would also understand it as meaning that _someone_ in particular is lacking trees, rather than it referring to just an objective dearth of trees.

Comment: That's just ridiculous, you are implying that the rules of grammar are subjective, which defeats the point of grammar as standardized use of language. Also in no way does the conjunction 'The' imply that 'someone' is lacking trees, but hey, it's your subjective grammar universe and what is right to you is right to us all now! The question was whether the form was wrong, not whether it's popular and strange. Also, choose an example that doesn't make your agruement Reducto ad absurdum. This person's English teacher is telling him it's wrong and no one can say why it's wrong. That simple.

Comment: 'Definite article' 'the'*